# llvm and clang installation on ubuntu

Tags: clang

So I'm trying to install [Halide](https://github.com/halide/Halide) on my Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit). I need llvm-3.2 and clang to be installed.

Running `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.2` ends up with 'package not found'.

Trying `sudo apt-get install llvm` or `sudo apt-get install clang` installs 2.9 versions. Google helped me with this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kxstudio-team/builds
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.2 clang-3.2` works. But when I run make in Halide folder I still get clang:Command not found.

Comment: I assume that "clag:Command not found" should read "clang:Command not found"?

Comment: yes, sorry about that

Comment: Are you using an Ubuntu with a GUI or one with just a command-line?

Comment: Also, do you need clang 3.2 or just clang 3+ ?

Comment: I downloaded the Desktop version. I actually need llvm 3.2, there is no word about the version of clang.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, so I successfully compiled Halide on Ubuntu 13.04 by installing `llvm`, `clang`, and `build-essential`. My only guess as to your issue is that the LLVM or clang from the PPA you installed might not have worked quite right. It seems it's actually possible to get LLVM 3.2 from Ubuntu for 12.04, via what is known as the "proposed" archive. You might try purging the LLVM you have and installing it from "proposed". I'll explain how to do that below. Since you mentioned you're new to Ubuntu (in the original question version), I'll first explain what each command you've already used does, as best I can.

So, `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.2` attempts to install the package named `llvm-3.2` from the current *repositories* enabled on your system. In your case, it couldn't be found, so the command failed. `sudo apt-get install llvm` installed the `llvm` package, which is probably a special package that just uses the most up-to-date LLVM available in your standard repositories. In your case, that was 2.9. Same idea applies to `sudo apt-get install clang`. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kxstudio-team/builds`
adds what's called a *personal package archive* or PPA to your system. This lets you get more software from another *repository*, or software source. See https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA for more info. Finally, `sudo apt-get update` tells Ubuntu to get information on what packages are available from the currently available repositories. You might take a look at http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html for more info on package management in Debian (most of which should apply to Ubuntu as well, since Ubuntu is based on Debian).

So, the steps to remove the packages you've got and install the versions available from precise-proposed:

1. Use `sudo apt-get purge llvm-3.2 clang-3.2` to completely remove LLVM and clang from your system.
2. (Optional) Use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kxstudio-team/builds` to remove the PPA from your system.
3. Follow the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed to enable the Proposed archive (right at the top of the page), and also follow the instructions for "Selective upgrading from -proposed". The first part will enable the actual Ubuntu version of the `llvm-3.2` package, and the second will keep the system from trying to upgrade everything to the Proposed versions.
4. Use `sudo apt-get update` to pull in the information on what packages and versions are now available.
5. Use `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.2/precise-proposed` to install LLVM 3.2, and use `sudo apt-get install clang/precise-proposed` to install Clang 3.0 (I think that's the version you should get).
6. **NEW STEP:** Do `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-config-3.2 /usr/local/bin/llvm-config` to make the system treat `llvm-config-3.2` (which is the `llvm-config` that came with `llvm-3.2`) as `llvm-config`. More completely, this creates a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or symlink) to llvm-config-3.2 in another place where Ubuntu will look for programs (more info: [ln](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln), [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html)). Thus, when you run "llvm-config", Ubuntu will find the symlink and run the program it points to (`llvm-config-3.2`).
7. See if everything compiles correctly now.

Hopefully that works. I've not tested any of this, so use at your own risk, etc. I'm pretty sure, however, that it shouldn't do anything terrible.

**EDIT:** Note that `llvm` and `llvm-3.2` are independent. `llvm` depends on `llvm-2.9` ([see here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/llvm)), while `llvm-3.2` is separate ([see dependencies here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/llvm-3.2/3.2-2ubuntu5~precise1))

Also, I'm not sure if you know about [tab completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion); it can be helpful if you're looking for a command but don't quite know the name (for example, in this case, it would probably have shown that `llvm-config` was called `llvm-config-3.2`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It almost worked. The only problem is that the installed llvm-3.2 doesn't have llvm-config. So when I run make in Halide it tells no llvm is installed. I ran install llvm and now llvm-config --version says 2.9. If I try to install llvm-3.2 it tells me it's the latest version. It seems that llvm-3.2 and llvm are completely independent.

Comment: See the new step in the answer; you'll probably want to uninstall the `llvm` package (`sudo apt-get purge llvm`) before you do it to make sure you get the right version. You can always check what file you're trying to run by using the command `which [command]`. For example, `which llvm-config` should read `/usr/local/bin/llvm-config`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_%28Unix%29 for more info.

Comment: why aren't llvm-config linked to llvm-config-3.2 just like it is for gcc? is this a conscious choice?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I believe it is a conscious choice. Since the version of LLVM that was available from the `llvm` package for Ubuntu 12.04 was `llvm-2.9`, the `llvm-config` command was linked to the `llvm-config` from the same version, i.e., `llvm-config-2.9`. In Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10, the `llvm` package installs LLVM 3.2, and I would expect it to then set up `llvm-config-3.2` as `llvm-config`, which it does in Ubuntu 13.10.