# have clang 3.4., need clang 2.9

Tags: software-installation, clang

i installed the default version of clang and llvm in my ubuntu 14.04 and it's version 3.4. That's nice, but for some legacy stuff i need version 2.9.

Ideally, i could install both version in parallel and use them with "clang-3.4 test.c" and "clang-2.9 test.c" while choosing which version a plain "clang test.c" refers to by default.

Indeed, the package for "clang" appears to be only 50KB in size, so something is going on.

Question: how can i have several version of clang installed in parallel?

llvm makes binaries for version 2.9 available on its website:

http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.9

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the main answer is **basically yes, you can**. I've googled your question and I've just got these answers:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/279329/can-i-have-two-versions-of-the-same-package-in-an-apt-repository
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/installing-two-glibc-alongside-in-debian-ubuntu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host
- [Install a different version of a package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30305/install-a-different-version-of-a-package)

My google keywords were: **install multiple version package in ubuntu**. CMIIW.

Comment: thanks, but all that only applies if the older version is in the repo. Also i couldnt find how to change what "clang" refers/redirects to. i fell like i am missing some term/expression in my google search... :/

Comment: Okay. I have changed my keywords to **install multiple version clang ubuntu** and I find:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962192/how-to-choose-the-llvm-version-clang-is-using
- http://askubuntu.com/questions/309786/llvm-and-clang-installation-on-ubuntu
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680533/install-llvm-3-4-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts